# finding the derivative of g' and h'

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

So I know i'm not too terribly far off of the wrong answer but i'm not sure where I went wrong so I was just looking for a little help here.
[image]

and sorry ahead of time but I don't know how to use the code here to make it look correct but this is the work I have done.
I got this from using the product and chain rule

number 1)))

g'(pi/3)= f(pi/3) * cos(pi/3) + sin(pi/3) * f'(pi/3)

= 3 * 1/2 + sqrt(3)/2 * -5

= (-15/2) * (sqrt(3)/2)

= (-(15sqrt(3))/2)

number 2

h'(pi/3)=(f(pi/3)(-sin(pi/3)-cos(pi/3)* f(pi/3)')/f(pi/3)^2

=3 * (-sqrt(3)/2) -1/2 * -5

= (((-3sqrt(3)/2)+ (5/2)))/ 25

= ((-15sqrt(3))/4)/25

Comment: dear rick, you have been on this site for 8 months, and you've already asked 22 questions. Please learn how to write in latex...

Comment: also, you should consider using the accept button sometimes... just saying...

Comment: what is the accept button? @user01123581321345589144...

Comment: it's the tiny green check mark under the down vote arrow

Comment: got it thanks.. see even though i've been on this site for 8 months I don't know much about it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$g'(x)=f'(x)\sin x+ f(x)\cos x$,

$h'(x)=\frac{-\sin xf(x)-\cos xf'(x)}{f^2(x)}$